# LXDM resolution too small on laptop when started with external screen

Tags: xorg, desktop, xrandr, login-manager

I have a laptop with small screen resolution, and when I connect external monitor before boot, it keeps resolution of the laptop screen, until I log in.

I'm using LXDM.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's because the screen "copies" the laptop screen - apparently both are enabled, even though one is closed under the lid.

In my case, the fix was easy:

edit `/etc/lxdm/LoginReady` and add a `xrandr` line you want:

In my case:

*FILE: `/etc/lxdm/LoginReady`*

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60.00 --same-as LVDS1 --output LVDS1 --off
```

You can obtain this line using `lxrandr`, when you "save settings", it writes it into `~/.config/autostart/lxrandr-autostart.desktop`.